# Were there rabbinic objections when grave digging went from manually-powered to machine?

Tags: history, technology, funeral-burial-levaya, cemetery-grave

There are lots of responsa when matza-baking machines were introduced instead of everyone doing it by hand. When power machinery came up to make grave-digging faster/easier, did any rabbis object that it was a bigger/better mitzvah or the like to do it manually?

Comment: I thought the matza issue was if it counts as lishmah

Comment: Even though there is machinery that can refill the grave, there is still a practice for people to shovel the dirt. Maybe this is a backwards proof that digging initially can be done by machine.

Comment: @Heshy that was a later concern. (And if you viewed them as kosher-but-not-lishmah, some were afraid they'd get used at the seder too.) Some declared them chametz entirely. Some worried about putting the humans out of business, or taking away the religious opportunity.

Answer (score 5):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus1 75:6](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=378) says that the grave should be dug by a Jew. [In the footnote](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=379) he says that a Jew should be the one who operates the tractor that digs up the ground.

There is no mention of any disagreement on that.